# Getting Wifi RSSI or signal strength using WlanAPI and IpHlpAPI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the wifi icon inside the Windows task bar using this library and C#.
https://github.com/dahall/Vanara

To get the current network interface I am calling GetBestInterface from IpHlpAPI and it seems to be returning the right index.  However I'm struggling on how to get the RSSI or signal strength value of the wifi network that's attached to this interface.  Using this data I could recreate the wifi icon with 1 bars, 2 bars, 3 bars, ect..

Using WlanAPI I can call WlanGetAvailableNetworkList which returns a list that has the signal strength value for each network.  There doesn't seem to be any data to connect these two things, so obviously I'm missing something.

Anyone have any ideas on the approach I should take?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to use [WlanQueryInterface function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanqueryinterface) with `wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection` to query various parameters of a specified interface. You could get a percentage value that represents the signal quality of the network from `WLAN_ASSOCIATION_ATTRIBUTES structure`.